# flutter widget does not appear after window was hide and show when using WindowManager plugin

Tags: windows, flutter

I am using WindowManager and TrayManager plugin to build my Flutter app, call `setPreventClose` to prevent the native close event:

```dart
await windowManager.setPreventClose(true);
```

then I override `onWindowClose` to hide the window instead of close the window like this:

```dart
@override
  void onWindowClose() async {
    bool _isPreventClose = await windowManager.isPreventClose();
    if(_isPreventClose){
      await windowManager.hide();
    }
  }
```

then I override `onTrayIconMouseDown` to show the window or focus the window:

```dart
  @override
  void onTrayIconMouseDown() async {
    bool isVisible = await windowManager.isVisible();
    windowManager.setPosition(_lastPosition);
    if (!isVisible) {
      await windowManager.show();
    } else {
      await windowManager.focus();
    }
    setState((){});
  }
```

then after I click clise to hide the window, click the tray icon to show the window,the widgets in app does not always show,just like this:
[no widgits show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIPEB.gif)

then I click the tray icon again,it shows,like this:
[widget shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UiDQ.gif)

if I resize the window widgets shows too.

so how can i sove this problem? I guess maybe flutter optimized the function `setState` cause nothing was set in the function?

My env:

windows11

Flutter 3.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision ee4e09cce0 (9 days ago) • 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700

Engine • revision d1b9a6938a

Tools • Dart 2.17.0 • DevTools 2.12.2

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment hide and use blur instead

and to my surprise it seems work

But i am afraid let it go this way to production

```
  @override
  void onWindowClose() async {
    if (Platform.isMacOS) {
      windowManager.blur();
    } 
  }
```

here is the solution
https://leanflutter.org/blog/click-dock-icon-to-restore-after-closing-the-window